# "Go to Source" for Latex on VS Code does not seem to work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to migrate to VS Code (on Mac) for creating and editing tex files. Everything has been working just fine except that, when I build and preview, I do not seem to be able to use the "Go to source" feature. In other words, I have a side by side split window, tex file on the left and PDF on the right, and what I wish do is to be able to click on the PDF preview and be taken to the source code on the left. Likewise, I would like to click on the code and be taken to the PDF on the right.

I have the LaTeX Preview extension installed which is supposed to do that, but the 'Show in Preview' button is absolutely inert, as well as double-clicking (or ctrl+click) the PDF. I have even considered the hypothesis that the name of the files might have had special characters, so I ran a test with a file named 'test.tex', and it still doesn't work.

I am digging around, trying to learn something about synctex in this [link](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View) but I'm really out of my element here. Would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I recommend installing [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) instead of LaTeX Preview.

Then use the following shortcuts for synctex (aka 'jumping' between `code` and `pdf`):

- from `code` to `pdf`:

  - mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>
  - windows/linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>
- from `pdf` to `code`:

  - mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>
  - windows/linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>

Make sure to enable synctex in the `settings.json`.

```
"latex-workshop.synctex.synctexjs.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.synctex.afterBuild.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, the latex-workshop.synctex.afterBuild.enabled value was "false". Must have been that. Working fine now. Thanks again!!

Comment: What are the commands on "normal" (not mac) keyboards? I found `"windows"+click` to go from pdf to code. What is the back?

Comment: To add to the accepted answer. On a Mac to go from pdf to code you use "command" + click.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Ctrl + click` on windows. It works for me according to this [issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1304#issuecomment-482891870) filed on GitHub.

Comment: I had LaTex workshop and everything updated and installed correctly. This worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for the problem is the (automatic) deletion of the `synctex` files. Some people dislike the cluttering due to the number of auxiliary files that are generated, and might modify the tex build to remove them. If the `synctex` files are deleted, this functionality is no longer provided, and the fix is simply to keep these files. I feel like this is a particularly easy problem to unknowingly create for newbies (talking from personal experience here), but did not find this answer on StackExchange.