# How to configure (if is possible) the Reverse Search with VS Code (with LaTeX Workshop)?, similar to WinEdt ReverseSearch preview

Tags: winedt, forward-inverse-search, vscode, latex-workshop

How can I configure (if is possible) the Reverse Search with VS Code (with LaTeX Workshop)? Similar to WinEdt's ReverseSearch preview.

[image]

Comment: If you're using LaTeX Workshop, using ctrl + click will let you jump from a point in your PDF to a location in your code. See the previous question ["Go to Source" for Latex on VS Code does not seem to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538797/go-to-source-for-latex-on-vs-code-does-not-seem-to-work)

Comment: Thank you @gz839918 Perfect.

Comment: @gz839918 any solution to the LaTeX Workshop preview?. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678304/how-can-you-improve-configure-que-vs-code-preview-winedt-and-texstudio-preview/679399#679399